# Android 10: BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor returns null

Tags: bitmapfactory, android-10.0

On an emulator running Android 10, when I use decodeFileDescriptor on a FireDescriptor as shown below, the bitmap is created fine. But when I try to set the options and then get the bitmap using that options object, the options object does not seem to be set right and the bitmap is null. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
Bitmap test1c = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed);
//This works
testImgView.setImageBitmap(test1c);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed, null, options);
//The line above sets outHeight and outWidth of options to -1

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//This bitmap object is null
Bitmap test1e = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed, null, options);
testImgView.setImageBitmap(test1e);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the reason why it was not working. The test I was doing at the start, was causing this issue.

```
Bitmap test1c = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed);
```

Because it looks like a ParcelFileDescriptor object can be used only once to generate the Bitmap. When I removed that line and tried out, it worked fine. Took me a couple of hours to figure this out, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely related to the problem, but we had this issue because of passing a non-null `paddingRect` to the method, which just made it return `null` without any mention of why.

```
Bitmap test1e = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed, new Rect(), options); // <-- bad
```

instead:

```
Bitmap test1e = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fdCompressed, null, options); // <-- good
```